# Hadoop not communicating with resourcemanager

Tags: hadoop

Hi currently I'm running hadoop 2.4.1. I have created a simple java program DefaultMapperClass.java using eclipse and packaged it into ex1.jar

When I try to invoke this program via hadoop shell using the command,

```
**hadoop jar /home/Maddy/ex1.jar DefaultMapperClass hdfs://localhost/users/root/input/Hadoop.txt hdfs://localhost/users/root/output**
```

I get the below output in hadoop shell

```
**[root@localhost Maddy]# hadoop jar /home/Maddy/ex1.jar DefaultMapperClass hdfs://localhost/users/root/input/Hadoop.txt hdfs://localhost/users/root/output
14/09/05 19:26:35 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Job started: Fri Sep 05 19:26:35 CDT 2014
14/09/05 19:26:35 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at localhost/127.0.0.1:8032
[root@localhost Maddy]#**
```

Seems like hadoop shell is trying to connect to resource manager but unsuccessful but there is no error message

mapred-site.xml file:

```
**<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn</value>
    </property>
</configuration>**
```

yarn-site.xml:

```
**<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
 </property>
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
<value>localhost:8032</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
<value>localhost:8030</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
<value>localhost:8031</value>
</property>
</configuration>**
```

What is missing here? Why execution is terminated after attempting to connect to resource manager?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest removing the following configurations from the `yarnsite.xml` as they are unnecessary :

```
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
<value>localhost:8032</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
<value>localhost:8030</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
<value>localhost:8031</value>
</property>
```

You can access the resource manager at localhost:8088